# Angular2 ngrx/store with route parameters

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, ngrx

I'm updating an app to use ngrx/store, but I can't figure out how to make it work with route parameters.

Currently, I am just using `ActivatedRoute` and using `this.route.params` inside the `ngOnInit()` of my components. So something like this:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.route.params
      .switchMap((params: Params) => {
        return this.item_service.get(params['item_id'])
      })
      .subscribe((item) => {
        this.item = item;
      });
}
```

Now that I'm using ngrx/store, I need to use an observable for the store. Basically I am trying to accomplish something like this:

```js
this.item = this.store.select('item').filter((item: Item) => {
    return item.id == magically_obtained_params['item_id'];
});
```

Is there a way to make this work?

---

Update (2016/12/06):

I added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41008754/1316229) to expand on [FunStuff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40968285/1316229), since it didn't fully provide what I want. I haven't accepted either answer, as I think there is likely a better way to deal with this.

To clarify my question, I am trying to make this work in a way that `this.item` is an `Observable`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Rx [combinelatest](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/combinelatest.md).

> Merges the specified observable sequences into one observable sequence
>   by using the selector function whenever **any** of the observable
>   sequences produces an element.

```
this.item = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(
    this.store.select('item'),
    this.route.params
);

this.item.subscribe([item, params] => {
   return item.id == params['item_id'];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got pointed in the right direction thanks to [FunStuff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40968285/1316229), but it didn't fully answer how to use `combineLatest()` in relation to an Angular2 component.

Here is the solution I came up with that allows you to set an `Observable` property on the component:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.item = Observable.combineLatest(
        this.store.select('item'),
        this.route.params
    ).switchMap(function(items, params) {
        return items.filter((item) => {
            return item.id == params['item_id'];
        })
    });
}
```

This works, but for my case I decided to go a step further. Instead of using `combineLatest()`, I moved the filter logic in the `switchMap()` into my service instead.

With this implemented, my component then looked like:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        this.item = this.item_service.getItem(params['item_id']);
    });
}
```

And on my service I have a method like this:

```js
getItem(item_id: string): Observable<{}> {
    return this.store.select('item').switchMap((items: any) => {
        return items.filter((item: any) => {
            return item.id == item_id;
        });
    });
}
```

I think I like this better since the component doesn't need to know about the `Store` at all, and it avoids needing to combine `Observables`.